# not able to build PHP 7.4 with apache

Tags: php, apache, build, package, httpd.conf

I am having troubles in building PHP 7.4 with Apache. It says httpd.h is not found though I am specifying the location of the top-level of my Apache source tree with the --with-apache option while configuring. Any leads can help me.

Comment: Is the file present  find / -name httpd.h?  You don't have the Apache header files installed at all or apxs is from wrong installation.

Comment: hello David, I am able to find the httpd.h in my workspace under my build directory. However, I am not sure why it still complains that it is not found. Also, the version I am using as of now: ./configure -V
configure
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69

Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This configure script is free software; the Free Software Foundation
gives unlimited permission to copy, distribute and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this error too. Use below to fix error (include c build src):

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/apache/include/:/usr/include/:/usr/include/apr-1/:/usr/local/include/
```

may this can help other people.